# Kendo AutoComplete

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to use kendo AutoComplete in a kendoGrid for inline editing. When user inputs anything I'd use it to call a RESTful web service to return a list of products with names that start with the input value.

My questions are:

1. My web service expects a request looks like `http://localhost/myService/appl` where "appl" is the value that user enters and the prefix. However, kendo seems to always format the request something like `http://localhost/myService?product=appl`. How do I change the format?
2. How do I get the value that user has input in the grid (the AutoComplete textbox) so I can pass it in the request URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define in the `DataSource` of your autocomplete an [`url`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read.url) function.

In that function, you can get typed value as:

```
var val = op.filter.filters[0].value;
```

and then return the url with the composed value.

Then it is something like:

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: function (op) {
                var val = op.filter.filters[0].value;
                return "/myService/" + val;
            }
        }
    }
})
```